# Why can I define this variable length array in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

Given

```
gcc -c main.C
gcc -lstdc++ -o main main.o
```

And main.C being

```
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    int somany; 
    std::cin >> somany; 
    double ex[somany]; 

    for(int i=0;i<somany;i++){ 
            ex[i]=0.03; 
            std::cout << ex[i]; 
    } 
}
```

Why does this not result in a compiler error? I thought C++ does not have VLAs?

Executing the program works just fine.

Comment: It's a gcc extension. You're right that it's not in the standard.

Comment: compile with [--pedantic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855121/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-pedantic-in-gcc-g-compiler) to ensure standard c++

Comment: How can I compile against the c++ standard only? Is there some flag for gcc? (g++ is not available for me atm)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios one second faster than me, thank you ;)

Comment: If anybody knows how to make the title of the question more specific feel free to edit.

Comment: This may be helpful
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles at all, despite linking against the C++ standard library, since you use .C and gcc. Or does .c vs .C take care of that? Yuck! Why not simply follow convention?

Comment: .C extension tells gcc that it is c++ code. At compilation you do not have to specify anything regarding the c++ std. It's only the linking where that is necessary AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a GCC extension and doesn't have anything to do with your approach of compiling with gcc then manually linking the C++ standard library.

The `--pedantic` compilation flag will typically disable such extensions.