# Isn't void in int main(void) redundant?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

The C99 standard document I have clearly states that

> *6.7.5.3.14* An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. **An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters.** The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

What I interpret from that sentence is that writing `void` in function definition is redundant. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: `main()` is a special case, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190986/is-int-main-without-void-valid-and-portable-in-iso-c) for discussion specific to `main`

Answer (score 5):

No, you're *slightly* wrong.

- `void` specifies that there is abosolutely no arguments passed.
- empty parenthesis `()` indicates that the function *can* be called with *any* number of arguments, without generating a warning.

**Note:** Remember, there is **no prototype** defined or supplied by the implementation for `main()`.

Maybe, `C11` standard, chapter 5.1.2.2.1, describes it better way,

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> ```
>   int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
>  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: The prototype bit is the important part here. If there is a function prototype (a.k.a. a function declarator that is not a part of a function definition) preceding the function definition as in `int main(void); int main() { ... }`, then obviously C99 6.7.5.3p14 (or the equivalent C11 6.7.6.3p14) would be applicable.