# C int main() vs. int main(void)

Tags: c, program-entry-point, c99, c11

As far as I know `int main(void)` is demanded by C99 an C11 standards. So `int main()` is not correct for the main function in this standards.

But which C (not C++) standard allows a `int main()` definition of the main function?

Thanks and regards Alex

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, the syntax is similar, but the semantics is not. There's no C standard which allows for a `main` function with unspecified arguments, and in C `int somefunction()` means something different from `int somefunction(void)`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, and it means even different things if this is found in a declaration (only) or in a definition.

Comment: So why my C compiler also except int main() { } as well as int main(void)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is int main() { } (without "void") valid and portable in ISO C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190986/is-int-main-without-void-valid-and-portable-in-iso-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between int main() and int main(void)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225171/difference-between-int-main-and-int-mainvoid)

Answer (score 4):

I personally clearly prefer the version with `(void)`, because it is usually better to declare functions with a prototype. But the form `int main() { ... }` is correct, too, as long as you use it in a definition and not a declaration, and in fact the C standard uses this form in a number of examples.

Here this defines and declares a function with no prototype, but for a definition it is clear that that function doesn't receive any arguments.

If you are trying to give a forward declaration of `main`, you shouldn't use that form, because there would be no warning if you called the function incorrectly. Here C and C++ are also different since C allows you to call `main` yourself, even recursively, where C++ forbids such things.

Answer (score 1):

According to C89 (http://web.archive.org/web/20030222051144/http://home.earthlink.net/~bobbitts/c89.txt) the `main` method is defined in two ways

```
int main(void)
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ...
}
```

As far as I know this is the first standard definition, so I would assume `int main()` is only defined well in the C++ standard.

However, I still use it :)

Comment: The linked C89 standard also says: "Program startup... It can be
defined with no parameters..int main(void) { /*...*/ }" I can't see anything about  a int main()

Answer (score 0):

If you are still unsure what to use after the other answers, i would recommend to have a define for empty parameters:

```
#if 0
 #define NO_PARAM
#else
 #define NO_PARAM void
#endif
```

in case of the main function you could then write

```
int main(NO_PARAM){
...
}
```

If you then change your mind later, you can simply use the preferred define without having the need to change all function signatures - which shall have no parameters - by hand.