# Function Not Working In My Program

Tags: c

My compiler says "too few arguments in the function". I can not figure out what is wrong. Does anyone have any idea on what I am doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int show(int a, int b, int c);

main( ){
int a, b = 10, c = 24;
printf("Enter a number\n");
scanf("%d\n", &a);
show(int a, int b, int c);
system("pause");
}

int show(int a, int b, int c){
if(a>c){
    printf("a is the largest number\n");
} else if(a>b){
    printf("a is smaller than c\n");
} else if(a<b){
    printf("a is bigger than b\n");
} else{
    printf("a is the smallest number \n");
}
return;
}
```

Comment: `show(int a, int b, int c);` inside the main to `show(a,b,c);`

Comment: Nothing in the code uses anything from `<math.h>` so you don't need to include that; you do use a function from `<stdlib.h>` so you do need to include that.  You should use an explicit return type on `main()` — that's required since C99.  Your declaration of `show(int a, int b, int c);` in `main()` uses a C99 feature — declarations at any point in the code — but doesn't include an explicit return type, but C99 requires that.  The code leaves a lot to be desired.  And you need to use more warning options on your compiler, and/or a newer compiler.

Comment: To follow up what @JonathanLeffler mentioned, `main()` is not a valid signature anymore, you should use `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `int main()` is a non-prototype definition of the `main` function (so if you call it with any arguments, you are treading on thin ice), but it is otherwise valid.  Definitely `int main(void)` is preferred, but `int main()` is not formally invalid in C99 or C11.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right, but **only** `main()` is pretty much invalid, correct sir?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Only `main()` is invalid; all functions must have an explicit return type specified.  It is best (by far) to ensure that they also have a full prototype, but the standard doesn't preclude `int main()` yet.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Functions with empty parenthesis (`int main()`) have however been flagged as obsolete style since C99 (future language directions) and therefore shouldn't be used.

Comment: Functions with an explicit `int` return type can also not have `return ;`, this invokes poorly-defined behavior if it is at all valid. Overall this code has numerous very fundamental problems. I'd consider getting a new source for learning C, your current one is apparently not helpful.

Comment: @Lundin: Actually, since C90 (§6.9.4 in C90).  I'm not arguing it is good; it is not.  But it is technically still valid, even though undesirable and obsolescent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I've argued that `int main()` is not valid according to a strict reading of the standard -- but on the other hand it's almost certainly the *intent* that it's valid, and I'd be surprised if any C compiler didn't accept it and handle it as expected. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29190986/827263 and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29190987/827263 (both mine).

Comment: just call it like `show(a,b,c);` instead of `show(int a, int b, int c);` inside `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared variables in a function call. It is not valid in C.

So, Use this:

```
show(a, b, c);
```

instead of

```
show(int a, int b, int c);
```

Comment: It is semi-valid C99.  It actually is another function declaration rather than a function call, but is missing the explicit return type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void  show(int a, int b, int c);

main( ){
int a, b = 10, c = 24;
printf("Enter a number\n");
scanf("%d\n", &a);
show(a,b,c);
return ;
}

    void show(int a, int b, int c){
    if(a>c){
        printf("a is the largest number\n");
    } else if(a>b){
        printf("a is smaller than c\n");
    } else if(a<b){
        printf("a is bigger than b\n");
    } else{
        printf("a is the smallest number \n");
    }
 }
```

here is is a complete code please use void in a function because if you use int you need some variable to handle that return variable in this function you don't need int so.try to use **return 0** instead of **system()**

> void  show(int a, int b, int c)
>
> int  show(int a, int b, int c)

Answer (score 0):

You defined your function as: `int show(int a, int b, int c)` but called it with improper arguments: `show(int a, int b, int c)`. What you should have done is call it with `show(a,  b,  c)` as `a,b,c` are already declared and defined

Comment: That's actually a second declaration of the function — not a call to the function.  It's sloppy C90 code because of the lack of return types.  It's invalid in C99 and C11.

Comment: so there are 3 declarations? before, inside and after main?

Comment: Yup — seems a bit redundant, doesn't it. :D

Comment: A bit :) but if so, shouldn't the error be redeclaration of show?

Comment: You can redeclare things as often as you want to — as long as the new declaration either hides a previous one or is consistent with the previous one.  The declaration uses 'implicit `int`' — not good.  But it is still a return type of `int`, the same as the explicit prototype at the top.  The declaration part way through the function is a C99 feature.  So it is confusing code.

Comment: I am a complete beginner. Does anything else need to be fixed in this code? It is compiling now, but when I enter a number and press enter, it does not continue.

Comment: If you changed your code, add an updated version, or show exactly what have you changed

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int show(int a, int b, int c);

main( ){
int a, b = 10, c = 24;
printf("Enter a number\n");
scanf("%d\n", &a);
show(a,b,c);
system("pause");
}

int show(int a, int b, int c){
if(a>c){
    printf("a is the largest number\n");
} else if(a>b){
    printf("a is smaller than c\n");
} else if(a<b){
    printf("a is bigger than b\n");
} else{
    printf("a is the smallest number \n");
}
return;
}
```

Comment: You haven't include `<stdlib.h>` but should.  And `main()` needs an explicit return type.