# Why is it allowed to declare an automatic array with size depending on user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, variable-length-array

I'm using MinGW to compile for C++11 and I found out that this doesn't throw an error:

```
int S;
cin>>S;
char array[S];
```

While this does ("storage size of 'array' isn't known"):

```
char array[];
```

To me, the size is also unknown in the first case, as it depends on what the user input is.

As far as I knew, automatic arrays are allocated at compile time in stack memory. So why wouldn't the first example fail?

Comment: Because you didn't disable compiler extensions.

Comment: The first was never originally valid in C or C++. In 1999 it was added to C, and some compilers will support it in C++ too. The compiler can add code to adjust the size of the stack when the array definition is reached. In the second case, no size is provided even at runtime.

Comment: see [Does “int size = 10;” yield a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21273849/1708801)

Comment: Note, this is an automatic array, not a static one

Comment: @Deduplicator Your edit kindof invalidated the question because it is not as surprising to determine automatic object sizes at run time...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Everyone handled that as just using wrong terminology which wasn't even worth pointing out. But feel free to Change those two words back, leaving only the rest.

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, he claims it was allocated at compile time which is surely not the case with automatic objects.

Comment: Now I'm confused... Why exactly is this not a static array and what is an automatic array?

Answer (score 19):

It's *not*. C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), though some compilers allow it as an *extension* of the language.

Answer (score 19):

You are apparently not aware of the GNU GCC extension [Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). Therefore your first code compiles.

The error message is something different. You have to specify the array length.

`gcc` has the [`-pedantic`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) switch - enabling this switch the compiler will report your first code as invalid:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘array’

Read also this thread [What is the purpose of using -pedantic in GCC/G++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855121/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-pedantic-in-gcc-g-compiler)

Use very carefully compiler extensions because should you port your code to another compiler then you are in *big trouble*.

Answer (score 3):

[This answers the original version of the question which asked about a static array; Deduplicator corrected this misconception, but now the question is missing a part.]

If your assumption that this piece of code defined a static array were correct, you'd be wondering for a good reason indeed: Something that is determined at *compile time,* like data with static storage duration, can obviously not depend on user input at *run time.* This truism is independent of any specific language.

The array defined in your code snippet has, by contrast, *automatic* storage duration, vulgo is created on the stack. A complete minimal working example would have made the case clearer: It would have shown that the code is in a function.

Objects with automatic storage duration can be created as needed at run time; there is no logical problem preventing that, which should fix your general headache ;-).

But note that, as some programmer dude correctly remarked, standard C++ nevertheless does not permit the definition of arrays whose size is not known at compile time; standard C does though, since C99. The rationale for C++ no following that amendment is that C++ provides better means for the use case, like the vector template. gcc, which is the compiler used in MinGW, permits this as an extension (and why not — it's available in the compiler anyway).

Comment: An arguably *better* alternative in `std::vector`, which is safer, and problems integrating dynamic-sized types into the type-system.

Comment: @Deduplicator I thought I said that part with vector ...

Comment: Hm. Perhaps I should have emphasized the *arguably*: It's safer but much more expensive. And anyway, the real kicker is the type-system.