# C++: Built-in arrays

Tags: c++

I thought that built-in arrays in C++ are statically allocated. But the following code works:

```cpp
//...
int x;
std::cin >> x;
const int cx = x;
int array[cx];
//...
```

Why does it?

Comment: That code works on *some* compilers that offer default-on extensions for variable length array. It doesn't work on other compilers and is not portable c++. You're being tricked by your compiler into thinking your code is valid c++. Another example of why you can't learn c++ by trial and error.

Comment: One reason Variable Length Arrays are bad: `x` can support numbers that are very big. Bigger than the amount of Automatic storage available to that array. Now multiply that large number by the size of an `int`. Using an array of that size will commonly manifest as a stack overflow and much debugging can ensue as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Variable length arrays are not part of the C++ standard, however your compiler allows it. If you use the `-pedantic-errors` option with your compiler (assuming g++), this will throw an error as [that option strictly enforces the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855121/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-pedantic-in-gcc-g-compiler).

Comment: `-pedantic` causes the compiler to emit warnings, not errors. You need to add on `-Werror` or `-pedantic-errors` to get an compilation-halting error. That said, `-Werror` is something I recommend to anyone learning C++. Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors and you should not ignore them.